# wget kali помогите со сертификатами

Tags: java, html, linux, kali-linux, wget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, пробовал --no-certificate (не помогает)

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикрепляйте текстовую информацию не картинками, а текстом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отключение проверки сертификата производится параметром `--no-check-certificate`. Ваш параметр хоть и похож, но не тот.

А то что сертификат заэкспайреный - немного странно, хотя может это и связано с недавней проблемой с сертификатами Comodo. А может обычный Men-in-Middle:) учитывая, что это Kali

Comment: Может на клиенте время неправильно установлено.

Comment: судя по логу - вроде нормально.